# unicity solution of an variational formulation setting \R^2

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$  with a periodic microstructure. More precisely, we scale this periodic structure by a parameter $\epsilon$ which represent the ratio of the cell size to the whole region \Omega and we assume that $0 < \epsilon <<1$ is a small parameter tending to zero. Let $C=[0,1] \times [0,1]$ be a periodicity cell. We pave $\mathbb{R}^2$ with Y. Inside $Y$ there are $B(0,\delta)$ where $\delta$ is a parameter represent the ratio of the cell size to the period

We consider the equation 
$$
\Delta u - q\left(\dfrac{x}{\epsilon},\dfrac{y}{\epsilon}\right) u=0,
$$
where q is defined by
$$
q(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
0, (x,y) \in B(0,\delta)\\
w , (x,y) \notin B(0,\delta)
\end{cases}
$$

We write the following variational formulation:
Setting $\mathbb{R}^2$: find function $u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ satisfying the following integral identity
$$
- \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \nabla u. \nabla v + q\left(\dfrac{x}{\epsilon}, \dfrac{y}{\epsilon}\right) u(x,y) v(x,y) dx dy =0
$$

How we prouve that the variational formulation admit a unique solution, and this solution is the solution of the strong formulation associating 
$$
\Delta u - q\left(\dfrac{x}{\epsilon},\dfrac{y}{\epsilon}\right) u=0,
$$?
And there are conditions on $\epsilon$, $w$ and $\delta$ to assure the uniquecess of solution of the variational formulation? Please.

Comment: Did you tried to use Lax-Milgram? Is $w > 0$?

Comment: Yes but for the continuity i have problem. What conditions on w and $\delta$ to have continuity?

Comment: As long as $w$ is just a real number, boundedness of your bilinear form is easy to obtain.

Comment: and for the coercivity? We have $$a(u,u)= -||\nabla u||^2_{L^2}+ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} q u^2 dx dy$$. How we conclude that $a(u,u) \geq C ||u||^2_{H^1}$? Please

Comment: Maybe $-a$ is coercive?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand